# PHP - MySQLi: Build query with "values" part

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a long insert query wich contains 10+ columns. I am looking for a compact way to build this query like:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi(...);
$mysqli->query("insert into table");
$mysqli->addKeyValue("columnName1", "value1");
$mysqli->addKeyValue("columnName2", "value2");
$mysqli->addKeyValue("columnName"3, "value3");
$mysqli->execute();
```

As far as I know there is no way to do this with default MySQLi. Is tehre a library that provides simmilar functionality?

**UPDATE:**

The reason I insist on trying to do something like this is I am trying to write code that doesnt exceeds 80-100 character limit per line to make my code more readable.

I know preapred statements and bind param.

Comment: Looks like a parameterized query and then `bind_param()` to me [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: I konw that but if you have lots of columns you still have to write them side by side. I want to add them one by one.

Comment: I dont see the difference, whats wrong with `bind_param()`

Comment: I can write my own lib but it would be nice if there is one already.

Comment: You are re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer you two libraries that can do what you want.

One is named [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo). With it you can do exactly the same way you wrote it in your question:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into table");
$stmt->bindValue("columnName1", "value1");
$stmt->bindValue("columnName2", "value2");
$stmt->bindValue("columnName"3, "value3");
$stmt->execute();
```

Another one is [SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) which I wrote to make mysqli usable. With it the approach will be different:

```
include_once 'safemysql.class.php';
$db = new safeMysql();
$data = [
    "columnName1" => "value1",
    "columnName2" => "value2",
    "columnName3" => "value3",
];
$db->query("insert into table SET ?u", $data);
```

as you can see, in both cases the line size doesn't exceed even 40 characters.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with `bind_param` this is so very similiar to what you are tring to do.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', 
                    $code, 
                    $language, 
                    $official, 
                    $percent);

$code = 'DEU';
$language = 'Bavarian';
$official = "F";
$percent = 11.2;

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

// add another row
$code = 'XXX';
$language = 'Yyyyyyyy';
$official = "Y";
$percent = 19.2;

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
```

> Shamlessly ripped off from the manual

Comment: The difference is, let say if you have 20 columns you have to write a very long `$stmt->bind_param()` line.

Comment: And this is not an answer to my question. This is my taste of writing code. I wnat to add each column value line by line.

Comment: I don't like very long code lines and I am trying to wire code that doesn't long more than 80-100 characters to make it more readable without scrolling horizontally.

Comment: How about doing it this way then

Comment: For not actually answering my question and asking "What is wrong with...". This should be a comment.